# MongoDB search using a date range and another condition

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to query the mongodb for documents having a 'date' attribute that is in a certain date range, this is how I'm doing it.

Q1.

```
$searchCriteria = array('$and' => 
        array(
            'date' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end),
            'lid' => $lid
            ));
```

Q2.

```
$results = $collection->find($searchCriteria);
```

It doesn't return anything, but if I run each search criteria separately, they work.

Q3.

```
$searchCriteria = array(
            'date' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)
            );
```

This works, it returns the documents that match this date range

```
    $searchCriteria = array(
            'lid' => $lid
            );
```

This works too, returns all lid's equal to what I have requested.

But when I want to AND these to conditions, it doesn't work, here is the var_dump of the search criteria Q1:

```
array(1) { '$and' => array(2) { 'date' => array(2) { '$gt' => string(10) "2010-11-10" '$lte' => string(10) "2010-11-12" } 'lid' => int(6209) } }
```

Here is the json_encoded output of the same query:

```
{"$and":{"date":{"$gt":"2010-11-10","$lte":"2010-11-12"},"lid":6209}}
```

Running the json output of the query in mongo shell results in an error

```
db.largedaily.find({"$and":{"date":{"$gt":"2010-01-01","$lte":"2010-01-02"},"lid":6209}});

error: { "$err" : "$and expression must be a nonempty array", "code" : 14816 }
```

What am I doing wrong? I think I'm setting the searchCriteria incorrectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A1/A2: You don't need the $and like that, instead use:

```
$searchCriteria = array(
    'date' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end),
    'lid' => $lid
);
```

On the shell, this `{"$and":{"date":{"$gt":"2010-11-10","$lte":"2010-11-12"},"lid":6209}}` is incorrect, as you need to use an array (with []) and not an object (which is {}). Correct is:

```
{"$and":[ {"date":{"$gt":"2010-11-10","$lte":"2010-11-12"} }, {"lid":6209} ]}
```

But you don't need the `$and` and you can just use:

```
db.largedaily.find( {"date":{ "$gt":"2010-11-10","$lte":"2010-11-12"}, {"lid":6209 } );
```

Comment: if $start & $end are  unix timestamps, it should be '$gt' => new MongoDate($start), '$lte' => new MongoDate($end)